# Transfer a repo from one bitbucket account to another

Tags: git, bitbucket

I hosted a repo in one bitbucket account. The code (repo) is running on a production server. I push the repo on production server to a brand new bitbucket account. Now on my local laptop, I point my the repo origin url from the old bitbucket to a new one. When I do git pull on local laptop I got:

```
Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/product_replacement'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.
```

`git branch -a` gives me:

```
product_replacement
remotes/origin/product_replacement
```

`git config -l` gives me:

```
branch.product_replacement.remote=origin
branch.product_replacement.merge=refs/heads/product_replacement
```

`git ls-remote` gives me:

```
7c2629311bb03fc153f743733374454b5961eaf0 refs/remotes/origin/product_replacement
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bitbucket "transfer repo" feature if you want to completely migrate the ownership of source code, wiki and other resources to another team / user account.

Please follow https://blog.bitbucket.org/2012/06/13/transfer-repositories/